# Python subtraction results zero?

Tags: python-3.x

This is very weird. I cannot post source code , but my problem is very odd. When I do print(var1 - var2) (where var 1 is 19 and var2 3) , it normally prints out 16. But when I try to assign this subtraction to a variable like :
var3 = var1 - var2 , it results in zero. Why? There is not much more to it. I just do this :

```
var3 = var1 - var2
print(var3)
```

This is so weird. I got into python recently , but I've never seen anything like this in the past. I also tried converting both values to integers , although they are already integers , but it did not help.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnmlZ.png)

Comment: Must be something simple, like a typo.

Comment: You don't need to post your source code, but you do need to post [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Your question is just nonsense otherwise.

Comment: could you add your python interpreter version?

Comment: Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 17:54:52) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32

Comment: @Alex Leence, ensure those values are really of integer type via ``isinstance()`` I never had values change via the dark arts, If they were changing, it was because I had called forth powers, that I didn't control yet. I propose you run this in a debugger and observer step by step which line of code executes and what  is changed by it.

Comment: Yup , both are integers. Just checked.

Comment: @Alex Leence, additionally it is important on SO to provide something we can work with. From what code you provided, we conclude your python is working as expected. Your image actually is unsettling, but is not showing a full example: which means all steps where values get assigned to the vars, all steps that handle those vars, minus those lines, that are not necessary to reproduce your situation. 
Cut out everything that is unnecessary in a way that the result still does the wrong result. You got those downvotes because of that "minimal, complete, verfifiable" yada yada

Comment: I found what causes the issue. If I remove the if statement , everything works. This if statement is what creates the bug. (I am walking about the if that is also captured on the image). No idea how to fix this

Comment: thats rather funny :D, how could the ``if`` which is not calculating/changing a value be responsible for a wrong result? Without seeing the code, I cant say. 
It seems like the matter wasn't a wrong calculation, but a wrong displaying of some results in a context, where it looked like it were the right results in the right context?

Comment: I am going to download a proper python debugger and see maybe that solves the issue. Thank you for the help. This must be the weirdest issue I've ever encountered :)

Comment: @Alex Leence, it is not my cup of tea to advertise but: check out pycharm. It is the one IDE/VisualDebugger I used and stuck to like a bear to honey.

Answer (score 0):

```
g@toolbox:~$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 10:45:20) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> var1, var2 = 19, 3
>>> var3 = var1 - var2
>>> print(var3)
16
>>>
```

Yeah it should be a typo :) I.e. what you showed as an example is not what your code is doing. Look over your code for reassignments of var1-3, use debugger and check the types of the vars in question.
It can help to

```
assert isinstance(var, int)
```

if unsure about the types.

Comment: Take a look at the image I added. It makes no sense. By the way , if I add instead of subtracting , it works!

Comment: @AlexLeence Your image indeed makes no sense. Because it doesn't at all show what you claim to be happening.

Comment: For some reason , when I try to subtract the values which are 19 and 3 , they magically become 2 , and the subtraction becomes 2-2. I have no idea why